# Steema VCL - trying to rotate a TPolarSeries.Pointer.Picture

Tags: delphi, rotation, teechart

[image: Aircraft not pointing at zero deg]

I am displaying an aircraft symbol at the center of a chart using a `TPolarSeries`. My series has one point `(angle,radius) = (0,0)`. I set the series property `series.Pointer.Picture.Bitmap = [my airplane pic]`.

I rotate the series labels 90 degrees so zero degrees is up (north).

I then rotate the series when processing user data by using the method `series.Rotate(Int([degrees]))`. The series labels move accordingly, but the aircraft (pointer image) does not rotate. I would like the aircraft to always point to the zero degrees label.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to also rotate the TBitmap (of the aircraft) - it's just drawing whatever's in the TBitmap, if you rotate it then it will draw the rotated version.

Comment: You don't need a charting library to draw this picture. Get rid of the `TChart` and draw the image yourself in the form's `OnPaint` handler.

Comment: Getting rid of TChart is not an option. My example shows the essence of the requirement I must meet using Steema products.